# how to append audio frames to wav file python

Tags: python, wav, pyaudio, pcm

I have a stream of PCM audio frames coming to my python code. Is there way to write frame in a way that appends to an existing .wav file. What I have tried is I am taking 2 wav files. From 1 wav file I am reading the data and writing to a existing wav file

```
import numpy
import wave
import scipy.io.wavfile
with open('testing_data.wav', 'rb') as fd:
    contents = fd.read()
contents1=bytearray(contents)
numpy_data = numpy.array(contents1, dtype=float)
scipy.io.wavfile.write("whatstheweatherlike.wav", 8000, numpy_data)
```

data is getting appended in the existing wav file but the wav file is getting corrupted when I am trying to play in a media player.

Answer (score 1):

With [wave](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/wave.py) library you can do that with something like:

```
import wave

audiofile1="youraudiofile1.wav"
audiofile2="youraudiofile2.wav"

concantenated_file="youraudiofile3.wav"
frames=[]

wave0=wave.open(audiofile2,'rb')
frames.append([wave0.getparams(),wave0.readframes(wave0.getnframes())])
wave.close()

wave1=wave.open(audiofile2,'rb')
frames.append([wave1.getparams(),wave1.readframes(wave1.getnframes())])
wave1.close()

result=wave.open(concantenated_file,'wb')
result.setparams(frames[0][0])
result.writeframes(frames[0][1])
result.writeframes(frames[1][1])

result.close()
```

And the order of concatenation is exactly the order of the writing here :

```
result.writeframes(frames[0][1]) #audiofile1
result.writeframes(frames[1][1]) #audiofile2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this also be useful

```
test_path1 = 
test_path2 = 
sample_rate,origin_signal1 = wavfile.read(test_path1)
sample_rate,origin_signal2 = wavfile.read(test_path2)

output = np.append(origin_signal1,origin_signal2)
display(Audio(output,rate = sample_rate))
```